Wordpress new role
We have planned to introduce new roles in Wordpress, these new roles are nothing to do with Civicrm, will the new roles impact the existing process of Civicrm. Thanks

Not unless you want them to - i.e. you give them CiviCRM permissions via the WordPress Access Control screen.
